# How will overstaying my Finnish visa affect future travel/visas?

Tags: schengen-visas, eu, overstaying, finland

[image]I used to study in Finland 10 years ago on a Finnish student visa. As my visa was expiring and I prepared to travel to my home country, I didn't ask for permission to stay longer. So I left Finland 15 days after my visa expired. When I transited in Frankfurt, I was stopped, questioned, my picture taken, and something written on my passport, and I was fined about 100-200€. That was in 2009 and I now have a new passport.

Can I apply for a travel visa to visit friends in Finland. Will my history of overstaying affect the outcome? If I don't apply to Finland, what about Germany?  With my history, can I enter any European country?

Comment: So what did they write into your passport?

Comment: If you apply, please come back and post an answer to let us know what happened.  We don't have much information about the future prospects of past Schengen overstayers, I'm afraid, in contrast to some other jurisdictions.

Comment: Thanks Giorgio. I will update what was written on my old passport later.

Comment: For reference: https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/aufenthg_2004/__95.html - §95 (1) 2.+3.

Comment: All in german, i dont understand. Can you find any english version? thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The word above your stamp ("Zurückgeschoben") means Removal, see [Section 57](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p1084) (link in English) of the "Act on the Residence, Economic Activity and Integration of Foreigners in the Federal Territory" as mentioned by user24582.

You can navigate to the other relevant sections in this document, like [Section 95 (1) 2+3](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p1753) (handwritten beneath your stamp) but it only gives you a feeling for what legally transpired ten years ago and no hint on what that means for your upcoming trip.

---

The following is merely my opinion:

I think your overstay would be taken into account by Finland and Germany in the same way, but how it would affect the outcome of your visa application is pure conjecture. If I were you and had positive travel history during these 10 years as well as a job to come back to on time, I wouldn't worry and apply for Finland.

Comment: Thanks Ewige Studentin, I feel better now. But I sent an email to Immigration Liaison Officer of German to ask the same question, will that be a problem for my future ?

Comment: I don't think that an email can have any legal consequences, but I also don't know whether you can get a specific advice this way. By the by, will you be travelling before or after July (in case you got a 10 year ban, which doesn't seem likely based on the small fine and short overstay)?

Comment: I havent apply for a visa yet. I just want to make sure before to do anything. so maybe the end of this year or next year.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no way to be sure. The best advice you can get is from a specialized attorney but even they wouldn't guarantee anything.

Comment: 1 more question, when i apply for a visa, should i bring my old passport with all the documents or should i hide it? What i say if they ask for it?

Comment: I'm not sure whether you are asked about your old passports or removals in your application. Don't volunteer any information if you are not asked but also don't lie or omit anything if you are.